# Why is the following true: "Dog" === ("Cat" && "Dog")

Tags: javascript

Why does the `&&` operator return the last value (if the statement is true)?

```
("Dog" == ("Cat" || "Dog")) // false
("Dog" == (false || "Dog")) // true
("Dog" == ("Cat" && "Dog")) // true
("Cat" && true) // true
(false && "Dog") // false
("Cat" && "Dog") // Dog
("Cat" && "Dog" && true) // true
(false && "Dog" && true) // false
("Cat" && "Dog" || false); // Dog
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/2d8WR/3/)**

Comment: Because that's what the spec says.

Comment: JavaScript's logical operators don't cast the results to boolean. They simply return one of the operands' values.

Comment: When using the && operator each side of the condition must be evaluated, since `Dog` is the last condition and the entire conditional is true, dog is returned.

Comment: I understand this question is pretty basic, but why the downvotes?

Comment: Non empty strings are "true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of [`&&` in *JavaScript*](http://es5.github.io/#x11.11) like this (based on *ToBool* from the [**es5 spec**](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2))

```
function ToBool(x) {
    if (x !== undefined)
        if (x !== null)
            if (x !== false)
                if (x !== 0)
                    if (x === x) // not is NaN
                        if (x !== '')
                            return true;
    return false;
}

// pseudo-JavaScript
function &&(lhs, rhs) { // lhs && rhs
    if (ToBool(lhs)) return rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

Now you can see that `ToBool("Cat")` is `true` so `&&` will give `rhs` which is `"Dog"`, then `===` is doing `"Dog" === "Dog"`, which means the line gives `true`.

---

For completeness, the `||` operator can be thought of as

```
// pseudo-JavaScript
function ||(lhs, rhs) { // lhs || rhs
    if (ToBool(lhs)) return lhs;
    return rhs;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

[Logical Operators - && (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

> **Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2.** Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both
>   operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

For your expression `"Cat" && "Dog"` , the first expression `"Cat"` can't be converted to false or a boolean value, hence it returns `"Dog"`

Comment: Looking at the spec like that, I can't help but think: _"Damn, that implementation looks like a hack"_. It is logical, though...

Comment: @Cerbrus I think it's pretty genius, not a hack. Why return a boolean, when you already have values which essentially act as booleans when necessary? That allows more concise constructs sometimes without really having any negative side effects.

Comment: @deceze: And that's exactly why it's the logical thing to do :P

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the && operator return the last value?

Because that's what it does. In other languages, the `&&` operator returns the boolean `true` or `false`. In Javascript, it returns the first or second operand, which is just as well since those values themselves are "truthy" or "falsey" already.

Hence `'Cat' && 'Dog'` results in the value `'Dog'`, which is equal to `'Dog'`.

Comment: Do you often start your answers with "Because that's what it does"?

Comment: Well, what other answer is there? :) The OP has already correctly identified how it works, and it works that way because the spec says so.

Comment: @FrederikWordenskjold: Would _"Because that's exactly what the spec says the `&&` operator does."_ be better?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah. That gives it an actual meaning. Otherwise, it sounds, at least to me, like the author is being deliberately unconstructive.

Comment: I think there's a Stack Exchange site dedicated to debating semantics. This answer as written is pretty constructive to me.

Comment: I'd vote for [semantics.stackexchange.com](http://semantics.stackexchange.com), where proper semantics get more votes than proper answers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Because you asked if `true === (true && true)`. If you use a non Boolean in a Boolean operation, javascript will convert to Boolean. Non empty strings are "true" so it returns correct.

Comment: If you're referring to the title example, `"Dog" == ("Cat" && "Dog")`, it is comparing `"Dog" == "Dog"`. `("Cat" && "Dog")` is roughly equivalent to `(!!"Cat" ? "Dog" : "Cat")`. The only boolean conversion involved is for the condition, not the results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the language designers wanted to enable users to use the || operator as a "coalesce" operator, in the style of e.g. the "null coalesce" operator ?? in C#.

In other words, if you want a default value, you can use the following idiom:

```
var x = input || "default"; 
//x will be equal to input, unless input is falsey, 
//then x will be equal to "default"
```